# Obrigar usuario a marcar pelo menos 5 campos input type number

Tags: javascript, html5, formulário, validação, number-format

Estou fazendo um site com contador com um botão mais e menos... Todos são do tipo input number com limite de 0 a 5 cada input.

São 33 input type number, desses 33 o usuário tera que ser obrigado a escolher no mínimo 5.
Estou vendo de desabilitar o botão submit se não for escolhido pelo menos 5 input. ou quando for clicar no submit de um aviso que o usuário deve escolher pelo menos 5 input...

Estou com um código que peguei e alterei para number ... era type text... com type text funcionava mais meu projeto esta todos os input com number. E não consegui fazer funcionar,

```js
// Mantém os inputs em cache:
var inputs = $('input');

// Chama a função de verificação quando as entradas forem modificadas
// Usei o 'change', mas 'keyup' ou 'keydown' são também eventos úteis aqui
inputs.on('keyup', verificarInputs);

function verificarInputs() {
    var preenchidos = true;  // assumir que estão preenchidos
    inputs.each(function () {
        // verificar um a um e passar a false se algum falhar
        // no lugar do if pode-se usar alguma função de validação, regex ou outros
        if (!this.value) {
          preenchidos = false;
          // parar o loop, evitando que mais inputs sejam verificados sem necessidade
          return false;
        }
    });
    // Habilite, ou não, o <button>, dependendo da variável:
    $('button').prop('disabled', !preenchidos);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" />
<input type="number" />
<input type="number" />
<button type="button" id="botao" disabled="disabled">Botão</button>
```

Tenho de dois tipo...

```js
$('input').change(function() {
    
    //habilita/desabilita botão
    $('button').prop('disabled', 
            $('input[type="number"]:checked').length < 5);
    
});
```

```html
<input type="number" name="group[001]" id="1">

<input type="number" name="group[002]" id="2">

<input type="number" name="group[003]" id="3">

<input type="number" name="group[004]" id="4">

<input type="number" name="group[005]" id="5">

<input type="number" name="group[006]" id="6">

<input type="number" name="group[007]" id="7">

<input type="number" name="group[008]" id="8">

<input type="number" name="group[009]" id="9">
    <hr/>
    <button disabled>Botão</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tem um erro na verificação, alterei umas linhas:

```
var inputs = $('input');

// Chama a função de verificação quando as entradas forem modificadas
// Usei o 'change', mas 'keyup' ou 'keydown' são também eventos úteis aqui
inputs.on('keyup', verificarInputs);

function verificarInputs() {

    var preenchidos = true;  // assumir que estão preenchidos
    var totalPreenchidos = 0; // numero total de preenchidos <--- adicionei esta variavel
    inputs.each(function () {
    // verificar um a um e passar a false se algum falhar
        // no lugar do if pode-se usar alguma função de validação, regex ou outros


        if (this.value == "" && totalPreenchidos < 5) { //<-- se o valor for diferente de vazio, ele não retorna um bool como estava, e verica se tem ao menos 5 preenchidos

          preenchidos = false;
          // parar o loop, evitando que mais inputs sejam verificados sem necessidade
          return false;
        }

        totalPreenchidos++; // passou então está preenchido, soma 1
    });
    // Habilite, ou não, o <button>, dependendo da variável:
    $('button').prop('disabled', !preenchidos);
}
```

O html é o mesmo

```
<input type="number" name="group[001]" id="1">

<input type="number" name="group[002]" id="2">

<input type="number" name="group[003]" id="3">

<input type="number" name="group[004]" id="4">

<input type="number" name="group[005]" id="5">

<input type="number" name="group[006]" id="6">

<input type="number" name="group[007]" id="7">

<input type="number" name="group[008]" id="8">

<input type="number" name="group[009]" id="9">
    <hr/>
    <button disabled>Botão</button>
```

Comment: Ainda não consegui :|

Comment: Publiquei no fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/zjLg8ke2/

Comment: Atenta de importar o Jquery antes, e que só vai liberar o botão se pelo menos 5 estiverem com números.

Answer (score 0):

Valeu Rogerio Santos me ajudou muito... Muito obrigado ...Porem não terminou ainda :| ... Fiz uma pequena modificação tambem..  No 'keyup' mudei para 'change' e no valor que estava vazio coloquei o zero ... porque os input iniciam no 0 estão com os value="0"... Mais vamos la. Como disse sou uma negação em javascript, e no projeto possui classes separas irei implementar esse código em apenas algumas classes.. mais não sei ao certo fazer isso ... fiz essa modificação no código mais não funcionou..

```js
 var inputs = $('.grupo');

 inputs.on('change', verificarInputs);

 function verificarInputs() {

     var preenchidos = true;  
     var totalPreenchidos = 0; 
     inputs.each(function () {
   

         if (this.value == "0" && totalPreenchidos < 5) { 

           preenchidos = false;
       
           return false;
         }

         totalPreenchidos++; 
     });
     
     $('.botaoenviar').prop('disabled', !preenchidos);
 }
  
 })(jQuery);
```

```html
<div class="grupo">

<input type="number" value="0">

<input type="number" value="0">

<input type="number" value="0">

<input type="number" value="0">

<input type="number" value="0">

<input type="number" value="0">

<input type="number" value="0">

<input type="number" value="0">

</div>

    <hr/>
    <button class="botaoenviar" disabled>Botão</button>
```